# Display JSONArray to ListView by adapter

Tags: java, android

I have an JSONarray that contains JSONobjects with a name and a direccion paramaters and i want to diplay it in a ListView. (All in a try catch block).

```
//A partir del string que contiene el JSON crearemos un Objeto JSON que contendrá la cadena
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset(this));

        //Creamos un JSONArray que contiene varios objetos JSON
        JSONArray m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray("librerias");

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> formList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> m_li;

        for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);
            //Log.d("Details-->", jo_inside.getString("formule"));
            String formula_value = jo_inside.getString("Nombre");
            String url_value = jo_inside.getString("Direccion");

            //Add your values in your `ArrayList` as below:
            m_li = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m_li.put("Nombre", formula_value);
            m_li.put("Direccion", url_value);

            formList.add(m_li);
        }
```

Then i create an ArrayAdapter who contains the JSONarray

```
//El ArrayAdapter hace de intermediario entre la ListView y el DataSource
        ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, formList);
```

And the problem comes when i show the info into a ListView, it show the info like the JSONArray format and i want to select how to display the info. It's possible?

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

At the output of the ListView i recive that in the same format:

{Nombre: Libreria Jose, Direccion: Calle Gran de Sant Andreu 382}

{Nombre: Libreria Jose, Direccion : Calle Compte d'Urgell 171}

Tnx all!

Comment: could you please post what you get as output ? you must be missing one more parsing step from JSONArray to string!

Comment: Updated!!!!!!!!

Comment: what is your JSONObject? and what would you like to show in the list ? You can create a custom adapter or use a different type for ArrayList

Comment: my JSON how i explain before, contains two parameters, a name and direction, and in the ListView I only want to display the name

Comment: ok please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first take a simpler List

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

then iterate over all your `HashMap` items in the current `formList` and add to the `list` based on what you need `key` or `value`

```
for (HashMap<String, String> map : formList)
    for (Entry<String, String> mapEntry : map.entrySet())
        {
        String key = mapEntry.getKey();
        String value = mapEntry.getValue();
        //if you need only keys to display in the listview
        list.add(key);
        }
```

then provide this list as a simpler datasource to your adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<List<String>> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<List<String>>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
```

finally set the adapter

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display only names, you can create an ArrayAdapter of `List<String>` instead of a hashmap, consider this way using your code:

```java
//A partir del string que contiene el JSON crearemos un Objeto JSON que contendrá la cadena
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset(this));

        //Creamos un JSONArray que contiene varios objetos JSON
        JSONArray m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray("librerias");


        List<String> m_li = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);
            //Log.d("Details-->", jo_inside.getString("formule"));
            String formula_value = jo_inside.getString("Nombre");
            String url_value = jo_inside.getString("Direccion");

            //Add your values in your `ArrayList` as below:
            m_li.add(formula_value);
        }
```

provide the list as data source to the array adapter and set the adapter to listview:

```java
ArrayAdapter<List<String>> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<List<String>>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, m_li);
```

`listview.setAdapter(adapter);`